# Specify the event A that the sum of two numbers showing is at most seven.

Tags: probability

Just need a quick confirmation about how I should interpret this question

```
Specify the event A that the sum of the numbers showing is at most seven.
```

Say the event A contains some ordered pairs of two numbers $(a,b)$.

1. Do I list down all the ordered pairs whose two numbers sum to seven: $a+b=7$
2. Or also include ordered pairs whose two numbers sum smaller than seven as well: $ 7\ge a+b $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the second one. You want $A = \{(a,b) | a+b \le 7\}$.

Alternatively, if $a,b$ are natural numbers, you can just list them...